# Хранение настроек Swing приложения

Tags: java, swing

Делаю приложуху на `Swing`. Нужно сохранять настройки приложения, но так что бы юзер не мог добраться до него, по крайней мере что б это был не файл ибо я не знаю где его хранить. БД не использую, если есть какая-то локальная бд как в андроиде дайте знать.

Смотрел на `WindowsPreferences`, но штука в том что она не работает - без вмешательства в реестр вручную работать не будет, а программно в `Java` я это сделать не могу.
Штука `Properties`, но она работает через `xml` файл. Где его хранить вне досягаемости от юзеров не знаю.

Есть ещё варианты?

Спасибо.

Comment: обычно настройки хранят в файлах в домашней директории пользователя или в директории с приложением. чем этот вариант не подходит?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman уже так и сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Ну во-первых на Java можно спокойно работать с реестром.
А во-вторых вы все равно не спрячете файл настроек таким образом, что бы юзер их не смог найти при условии наличия у него прав Администратора. Если их у него нет - то да, можно в ту же папку где стоит софт записать или в тот же реестр. Главное что бы прав на доступ обычным юзерам к этому месту не было.
А вообще не думаю, что надо заморачиваться. Храните настройки в бинарном виде + шифруйте файл.

Для работы с реестром можно использовать такие конструкции:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class WinRegistry {
    public static final int HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = 0x80000000;
    public static final int HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001;
    public static final int HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
    public static final int REG_SUCCESS = 0;
    public static final int REG_NOTFOUND = 2;
    public static final int REG_ACCESSDENIED = 5;

    private static final int KEY_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf003f;
    private static final int KEY_READ = 0x20019;
    private static Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
    private static Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
    private static Class<? extends Preferences> userClass = userRoot.getClass();
    private static Method regOpenKey = null;
    private static Method regCloseKey = null;
    private static Method regQueryValueEx = null;
    private static Method regEnumValue = null;
    private static Method regQueryInfoKey = null;
    private static Method regEnumKeyEx = null;
    private static Method regCreateKeyEx = null;
    private static Method regSetValueEx = null;
    private static Method regDeleteKey = null;
    private static Method regDeleteValue = null;

    static {
        try {
            regOpenKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey",
                    new Class[]{int.class, byte[].class, int.class});
            regOpenKey.setAccessible(true);
            regCloseKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCloseKey",
                    new Class[]{int.class});
            regCloseKey.setAccessible(true);
            regQueryValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryValueEx",
                    new Class[]{int.class, byte[].class});
            regQueryValueEx.setAccessible(true);
            regEnumValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumValue",
                    new Class[]{int.class, int.class, int.class});
            regEnumValue.setAccessible(true);
            regQueryInfoKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryInfoKey1",
                    new Class[]{int.class});
            regQueryInfoKey.setAccessible(true);
            regEnumKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                    "WindowsRegEnumKeyEx", new Class[]{int.class, int.class,
                            int.class});
            regEnumKeyEx.setAccessible(true);
            regCreateKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                    "WindowsRegCreateKeyEx", new Class[]{int.class,
                            byte[].class});
            regCreateKeyEx.setAccessible(true);
            regSetValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                    "WindowsRegSetValueEx", new Class[]{int.class,
                            byte[].class, byte[].class});
            regSetValueEx.setAccessible(true);
            regDeleteValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                    "WindowsRegDeleteValue", new Class[]{int.class,
                            byte[].class});
            regDeleteValue.setAccessible(true);
            regDeleteKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                    "WindowsRegDeleteKey", new Class[]{int.class,
                            byte[].class});
            regDeleteKey.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private WinRegistry() {
    }

    /**
     * Read a value from key and value name
     *
     * @param hkey      HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param key
     * @param valueName
     * @return the value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static String readStringUTF(int hkey, String key, String valueName)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            return readStringUTF(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            return readStringUTF(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    public static String readString(int hkey, String key, String valueName)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            return readString(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            return readString(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read value(s) and value name(s) form given key
     *
     * @param hkey HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param key
     * @return the value name(s) plus the value(s)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static Map<String, String> readStringValuesUTF(int hkey, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            return readStringValuesUTF(systemRoot, hkey, key);
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            return readStringValuesUTF(userRoot, hkey, key);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the value name(s) from a given key
     *
     * @param hkey HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param key
     * @return the value name(s)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static List<String> readStringSubKeys(int hkey, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            return readStringSubKeys(systemRoot, hkey, key);
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            return readStringSubKeys(userRoot, hkey, key);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a key
     *
     * @param hkey HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param key
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void createKey(int hkey, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        int[] ret;
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            ret = createKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
            regCloseKey.invoke(systemRoot, new Object[]{new Integer(ret[0])});
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            ret = createKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
            regCloseKey.invoke(userRoot, new Object[]{new Integer(ret[0])});
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
        if (ret[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + ret[1] + "  key=" + key);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write a value in a given key/value name
     *
     * @param hkey
     * @param key
     * @param valueName
     * @param value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void writeStringValueUTF
    (int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            writeStringValueUTF(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            writeStringValueUTF(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    public static void writeStringValue
            (int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            writeStringValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            writeStringValue(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete a given key
     *
     * @param hkey
     * @param key
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void deleteKey(int hkey, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        int rc = -1;
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            rc = deleteKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            rc = deleteKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
        }
        if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key);
        }
    }

    /**
     * delete a value from a given key/value name
     *
     * @param hkey
     * @param key
     * @param value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void deleteValue(int hkey, String key, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        int rc = -1;
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            rc = deleteValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, value);
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            rc = deleteValue(userRoot, hkey, key, value);
        }
        if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key + "  value=" + value);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] readValue(int hkey, String key, String valueName)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            return readValueData(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            return readValueData(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    // =====================

    private static int deleteValue
            (Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{
                new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS)});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            return handles[1];  // can be REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED
        }
        int rc = ((Integer) regDeleteValue.invoke(root,
                new Object[]{
                        new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value)
                })).intValue();
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{new Integer(handles[0])});
        return rc;
    }

    private static int deleteKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        int rc = ((Integer) regDeleteKey.invoke(root,
                new Object[]{new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key)})).intValue();
        return rc;  // can REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED, REG_SUCCESS
    }

    private static byte[] readValueData(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ)});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] valb = (byte[]) regQueryValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[]{new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value)});
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{new Integer(handles[0])});
        return valb;
    }

    private static String readStringUTF(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        byte[] valb = readValueData(root, hkey, key, value);
        //return (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
        String result = null;
        if (valb != null) {
            try {
                result = new String(valb, "UTF-8").trim();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WinRegistry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String readString(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        byte[] valb = readValueData(root, hkey, key, value);
        return (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> readStringValuesUTF
            (Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{
                new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ)});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            return null;
        }
        int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root,
                new Object[]{new Integer(handles[0])});

        int count = info[0]; // count
        int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumValue.invoke(root, new Object[]{
                    new Integer
                            (handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)});
            String value = readStringUTF(hkey, key, new String(name));
            results.put(new String(name).trim(), value);
        }
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{new Integer(handles[0])});
        return results;
    }

    private static List<String> readStringSubKeys
            (Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{
                new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ)
        });
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            return null;
        }
        int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root,
                new Object[]{new Integer(handles[0])});

        int count = info[0]; // Fix: info[2] was being used here with wrong results. Suggested by davenpcj, confirmed by Petrucio
        int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[]{
                    new Integer
                            (handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)
            });
            results.add(new String(name).trim());
        }
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{new Integer(handles[0])});
        return results;
    }

    private static int[] createKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        return (int[]) regCreateKeyEx.invoke(root,
                new Object[]{new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key)});
    }

    private static void writeStringValueUTF
            (Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{
                new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS)});

        regSetValueEx.invoke(root,
                new Object[]{
                        new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(valueName), UTFtoCstr(value)
                });
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{new Integer(handles[0])});
    }

    private static void writeStringValue
            (Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{
                new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS)});

        regSetValueEx.invoke(root,
                new Object[]{
                        new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(valueName), value.getBytes()
                });
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{new Integer(handles[0])});
    }

    // utility
    private static byte[] toCstr(String str) {
        byte[] result = new byte[str.length() + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            result[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
        }
        result[str.length()] = 0;
        return result;
    }

    private static byte[] UTFtoCstr(String str) {
        try {
            byte[] data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] result = new byte[data.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, result, 0, data.length);
            result[data.length] = 0;
            return result;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            return toCstr(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Что касается того как быть на разных платформах, то вам надо абстрагировать реализацию при помощи интерфейса. Т.е. вы описываете интерфейс, указывая базовые для всех платформ методы (загрузить, сохранить, добавить значение, прочитать значние и т.п.) а потом делаете столько реализаций интерфейса, сколько будете поддерживать платформ. И уже в реализациях будет для Win например - реестр, для Linux - файлы и т.д.

Comment: Я читал о том что нельзя. Подскажите как это сделать? Проблема в том что для работы `Preferences` нужна созданная запись в реестре, но её нет. И её нужно создать. как это сделать?

Ну допустим файл можно хранить в папке юзера на диске с виндой. А как быть с Маком? Линукс? Ведь `jar` файл можно запустить и на маке и на линуксе, если `java` установлена конечно.

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил реализацию

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать сервисы хранения текстов (например Pastebin)
но придется помучатся с отправкой/получением данных, аккаунтами
но зато если будешь использовать https, шифрование исполняемого файла то будет невозможно дораться к такой инфе